# Universal Binary supporting i386, x86_64 and PPC

Tags: macos, universal-binary

Can you build an OSX program supporting i386, x86_64 and PPC at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Xcode, you don't have to use lipo, just list those architectures in the Architectures [ARCHS] build setting.  Of course, you can't use Xcode 4, as it does not support ppc.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would seem to be yes, [you combine them all](http://ngmarley.com/blog/osx-universal-binary/) with the lipo tool.